# Wordpress how to echo Category ID as class name in Recent Posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve a list of posts in a custom widget in wordpress and I'd like to assign each li a class name based on the category name (or slug) of each item. I think I'm close but alas my classnames are showing empty. I'm not the greatest with PHP I'm sure it's a syntax issue...here's where I'm at so far:

```
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $categories = get_the_category($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li class="' . $categories["Post_ID"]->slug . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure $categories[Post_ID"] is wrong- I can get it to print the slug of a certain category if I put a specific category ID in there- but then it's the same regardless of the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_category` is expecting a `post_id`, not an array of posts.

Try something like

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    $categories = get_the_category($recent["ID"]);
    echo '<li class="' . $categories[0]->slug . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
```

I'm not sure if the key name is actually "ID" or "Post_ID" (you seem to be using both). Please check that too.

Comment: works! It was "ID" :) You just saved me so much time, thank you so much!!